# is this code verbose or am I misunderstanding it?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, put

I see this code in a book, as an example of creating an object (Employee, in this case) with the client providing the ID:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, Employee employee)
{
    if (!list.Any(e => e.Id == id)
    {
        list.Add(employee);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Employee>(HttpStatusCode.Created, employee);

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = employee.Id });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

I see how this works, but wouldn't the following abbreviated code work as well:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(Employee employee)
{
    if (!list.Any(e => e.Id == employee.Id)
    {
        list.Add(employee);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Employee>(HttpStatusCode.Created, employee);

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = employee.Id });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

?

Comment: Is the route `api/employee/{id}` with a `PUT` verb?  If so, you'll need the `id` parameter.

Comment: @David why would you need the id as an argument if the employee argument already has the same assigned?

Comment: @varevarao Perhaps convention; perhaps the model being passed up doesn't have the id defined.  Perhaps to be REST-compliant as you're updating an existing resource that should be reachable by a unique URI.

Comment: I agree with the model not having the id defined. Though this'd be a pretty silly thing to ask in that case. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggested less-verbose solution is not wrong, it just changes the default mechanism for how the ASP.NET Web API looks for the values you are passing in.

`id` is a simple type, so the ASP.NET Web API will look in the request URI for the value, whereas `Employee` is a complex type so the ASP.NET Web API needs to look in the request body. So if you have a route setup that requires the `id` be a part of the URI, then it would make more sense to make the `id` be a separate parameter, as it will be picked off the URI automatically.

You can instruct the ASP.NET Web API to look in the request URI by using the `[FromUri]` attribute in your parameter, like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromUri]Employee employee)
{

}
```

Now if you pass the constituent parts of an `Employee` object in the query string of the request, then the ASP.NET Web API will pick out those pieces of information and build an `Employee` object from, like this:

```
http://localhost/api/values/?FirstName=John8&LastName=Doe
```

> Note: I am making up the `FirstName` and `LastName` names, but they would need to match `public` properties of your model class.

---

For more information read [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Answer (score 2):

If your route/api method for `PUT` is defined as `api/employee/{id}`, then you'll need `id` passed in.  However, if your `Employee` object already has the ID, then you could just have a route of `api/employee` for the `PUT` verb and just accept the `Employee` object like your second example shows.

From an [example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations) for Web API, the documentation states:

> By default, the ASP.NET Web API framework takes simple parameter types
>   from the route and complex types from the request body.